# Error on boot could not resolve symbol [\sb.pc10.gpp1.ptxh.rhub.pot9]

Tags: acpi

I'm brand new to linux and just installed Kubuntu fresh on a new computer. but I get this error when booting.

I previously had manjaro installed without any issues or errors.

[image: ACPI error]

Comment: You can ignore ACPI errors as long as they don't block boot

Comment: **Not all BIOSes implement the complete ACPI stack and tree.** These BIOS errors and ACPI Errors of **this specific case** are non-critical issues.  There's no way to fix those because that's up to the manufacturer of the motherboard and BIOS to implement everything.  It's not atypical to see this on most systems in some fashion with ACPI BIOS errors of various ways.  Those are USUALLY non-critical.